# Sort lines by length with automator?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, unix, automator

I have a [text document](http://designbyadmiral.com/transfer/dune.txt) (1MB, TXT file) with a little more than 17,500 lines. What I'm hoping to be able to do is to sort those lines by character length and have it output to either the same file (which is then saved) or a new file entirely. Either one works fine as long as I know ahead of time.

Bonus points if I could do it through Automator in OS X in some way as my coding/terminal abilities are... Lacking.

Comment: Is this homework or you actually have no idea on how to do it?

Comment: No idea how to do it. It's for a little side project I'm doing some preliminary work on. I'm a web designer (note the base URL of the link).

Comment: For the sake of speed, I would definitely not recommend Automator or Applescript for this type of work. You would be much better off finding some kind of solution in the Terminal.

Comment: I think you already asked this question here 
http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=12077242

Comment: Yeah, because I wasn't getting anywhere there I thought, hey, why not try a developer community. Thanks for the help. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the file to XML then used XSLT to order the entries based on string length. It was a really long way around but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

awk '{printf "%7d %s\n", length($0), $0}' file | sort -n | sed -e 's/^....... //' > newfile

print each line with its length before it in a 8 character field
sort that output numerically
strip off the 8 characters from the front of each line

This works if each line of your file has fewer than 10M characters. Since your file is less than 1MB that must be true.